# WakefulBroadcastReceiver for GCM not triggering

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, google-cloud-messaging

Okay I've searched this topic and had implemented every possible thing, still no success.
This is the receiver class

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ComponentName;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.support.v4.content.WakefulBroadcastReceiver;
import android.util.Log;

public final class MyGcmBroadcastReceiver extends  WakefulBroadcastReceiver {


@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

            Log.d("output something","Output");
            ComponentName comp = new ComponentName(context.getPackageName(),
            MyGcmIntentService.class.getName());
            startWakefulService(context, (intent.setComponent(comp)));
            setResultCode(Activity.RESULT_OK);

}
}
```

And this is the content of the  menifest
Note: that I am using a different package from different library which contains the receiver and the intentservice

```
 <receiver
        android:exported="false"
        android:name="lib.package.name.MyGcmBroadcastReceiver"
        android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action      android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION" />
        </intent-filter>
         <category android:name="my.demo.app" />
    </receiver>
    <service  android:exported="false" android:name="lib.package.name.MyGcmIntentService" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
  <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.RECEIVE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <permission android:name="my.demo.app.permission.C2D_MESSAGE"  android:protectionLevel="signature" />
  <uses-permission android:name="my.demo.app.permission.C2D_MESSAGE" />
```

The server is throwing 
"multicast_id":8642316007520492123,"success":1,"failure":0,"canonical_ids":0,"results":

My GCM intent Service

```
public final class MyGcmIntentServiceextends GcmListenerService{
public static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1;   
NotificationCompat.Builder builder;

public MyGcmIntentService() {

    Log.d("Test GCMMMMMMMMM","GCM  SDS");
}

String app_tag="MyGcmIntentService->MyGcmIntentService";

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(String from, Bundle data) {
      String message = data.getString("message");
        Log.d(app_tag, "From: " + from);
        Log.d(app_tag, "Message: " + message);

        /**
         * Production applications would usually process the message here.
         * Eg: - Syncing with server.
         *     - Store message in local database.
         *     - Update UI.
         */

        /**
         * In some cases it may be useful to show a notification indicating  to the user
         * that a message was received.
         */
        sendNotification("web-demo",message);
}
```

And I cannot see any output in the logcat.
Please help me out people!

Answer (score 0):

Can you also post your MyGcmIntentService?

Implemenation of GCM according to  [Google developers](https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/android/client) , Google recommends migrating to GCMReceiver and GcmListenerService. Also,

1. In the app manifest, replace your GcmBroadcastReceiver with `"com.google.android.gms.gcm.GcmReceiver"`, and replace the current service declaration that extends IntentService to the new GcmListenerService.
2. Remove the BroadcastReceiver implementation from your client code.
3. Refactor the current IntentService service implementation to use GcmListenerService.
   Please also take a look at this  [tutorial](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Google-Cloud-Messaging) .

Comment: Thank you. Will try that soon

Comment: Also consider the device where you test your app. GCM only works on Android 2.2+ .

Comment: Ive edited my question and had added my Intent Service codes. Please have a look. Its not triggering. I have replaced the code in menifest as you have said.

Comment: Jaye. Thank you it worked. I missed to add  

<action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE" />